# Speed up indices finding in numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I have a 1d numpy array of strings `(dtype='U')` called `ops` of length 15MM where I need to find all the indices where I find a string called `op` 83,000 times.

So far numpy is winning the race, but it still takes like 3 hours: `indices = np.where(ops==op)`
I also tried `np.unravel_index(np.where(ops.ravel()==op), ops.shape)[0][0]` without much of a difference.

I'm trying a cython approach with random data similar to the original, but its about 40 times slower than numpys solution. It's my first cython code maybe I can improve it.
Cython code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def get_ixs(np.ndarray data, str x, np.ndarray[int,mode="c",ndim=1] xind):
    cdef int count, n, i
    count = 0
    n = data.shape[0]
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if (data[i] == x):
            xind[count] = i
            count += 1
        i += 1

    return xind[0:count]
```

Comment: I don't really see why Cython would be expected to to beat `numpy.where` here. You're maybe saving the creation of one temporary array. It might be worth trying with a Python list of unicode strings instead of a Numpy array - although it sounds counter-intutirve it's possible that you have lots of inefficient Numpy C string<->Python string conversions that you could be avoiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `get_ixs` several times with the same `data`, the fastest solution is to preprocess `data` into a `dict` to then get O(1) lookups (constant time) when querying strings.
A key of the dict is a string `x` and the value for this key is a list containing the indices satisfying `data[i] == x`.
Here is the code :

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array(["toto", "titi", "toto", "titi", "tutu"])

indices = np.arange(len(data))
# sort data so that we can construct the dict by replacing list with ndarray as soon as possible (when string changes) to reduce memory usage
indices_data_sorted = np.argsort(data)  
data = data[indices_data_sorted]
indices = indices[indices_data_sorted]

# construct the dict str -> ndarray of indices (use ndarray for lower memory consumption)
dict_str_to_indices = dict()
prev_str = None
list_idx = []  # list to hold the indices for a given string
for i, s in zip(indices, data):
    if s != prev_str:  
        # the current string has changed so we can construct the ndarray and store it in the dict
        if prev_str is not None:
            dict_str_to_indices[prev_str] = np.array(list_idx, dtype="int32")
        list_idx.clear()
        prev_str = s
    list_idx.append(i)
    
dict_str_to_indices[s] = np.array(list_idx, dtype="int32")  # add the ndarray for last string

def get_ixs(dict_str_to_indices: dict, x: str):
    return dict_str_to_indices[x]

print(get_ixs(dict_str_to_indices, "toto"))
print(get_ixs(dict_str_to_indices, "titi"))
print(get_ixs(dict_str_to_indices, "tutu"))
```

Output :

```
[0 2]
[1 3]
[4]
```

If you call `get_ixs` many times with the same `dict_str_to_indices`, it is the optimal asymptotic solution ( O(1) lookup).

Comment: Sure, but how do I feed the values of each key? (finding the indices of each string coincidence in the array)

Comment: I'm going to update my answer with the code

Comment: if `i` is a list `data[i]` is a list and it can't be compared to a string `x` with `data[i]==x`. But my question is how do I find the `i` list cointaining the indices of `x` in `data` in the first place.

Comment: I meant the value is a list of integer and each of them satisfy data[i] == x. I update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Marked as answer, this was about 15 times faster than numpy in the test. But memory could be a problem as data scales (it crashed my pc)

Comment: Indeed I updated my answer with a better code for memory ;-)
The trick is to store the indices in a numpy array instead of a python list.
This is because integers in a numpy array takes much lesser space than in a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226396/discussion-between-ismael-el-atifi-and-oliver-mohr-bonometti).